# React Native - How to overlay a modal style window over the launcher, rather than full screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native

An example of what I mean is this app, [Be Reminded.] Specifically I'm interested in how to do this on Android if it matters.
(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.jagdos.notification&hl=en)

[image]

Comment: How did you end up solving this? Do you have a solution you could share? :)

Comment: Never went further down this line, although I believe Sricharan's answer was close.

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you use Modal with navigator? Else, setting style={{position:'absolute'}} will also create an overlay to which height and width can be set.

Comment: It's not that I can't, but rather that I am just starting out with React-Native (have experience with React) but this is a critical feature for me, so I want to ensure that it's possible firstly, and secondly learn how to implement it.

Comment: Can you please clarify, is this possible to do at the top level? This seems only to be a method for creating a modal over my own application. How can I do this over the launcher? No matter what I do I get a full screen app with a white background. Setting backgrounds as transparent or changing sizes doesn't make a difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you write a native code for it and connect it with RCTBridge? You can also create a module for it to others to use.

Here is a reference link : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll investigate what you linked.

Comment: Let me know if I can be any help. Would love to contribute. :)

Answer (score 1):

in the AndroidManifest.xml change the theme to  following for the MainApplication

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

and for the mainactivity Activity, add entry..

```
android:background="#80000000"
```

finally in the top level View style of the react native app use following style.

```
container: {
position: 'absolute',
top: 100,
right: 100,
bottom: 100,
left: 100,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try this as soon as I can and accept as answer if it works. This change to the manifest file seems likely to be the crucial bit I was missing.